# JUnit does not read test methods

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am trying to use JUnit in order to test a queue implementation I did, but I am having an issue: is like JUnit can't find my test methods. Does anyone know how to resolve such an issue?

[image: Junit]

[image: Junit]

For more clarification, this is the issue Eclipse raises

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/ConfigurationParameters
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.<init>(JUnit5TestLoader.java:34)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:350)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createRawTestLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.defaultInit(RemoteTestRunner.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.init(RemoteTestRunner.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.engine.ConfigurationParameters
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 13 more
```

And this is my test class as well.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;


import java.lang.String;
import org.junit.Before; 
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class QueueTest {
    private Queue qq;
 
    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        
        qq = new Queue<Integer>();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testInitialState()
    {
           
        
        
    }

   
    @Test
    public void testAddElement()
    {
       
    
    }

    @Test
    public void testHowMany()
    {
       
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetElement()
    {
        
    }

    @Test
    public void testTimings()
    {
       
    }


}
```

I also tried changing the version of JUnit from 5 to 4 but nothing changes, might the issue be related to the build path?
Thanks,

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in Eclipse 2020-12. Do you have an outdated version? `org.junit.Before` is JUnit 4 and has to be `org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach` instead. When switching the JUnit version, make also sure to change in the JUnit run configuration the _Test runner_.

Comment: I have the 4.18 version

Comment: There is no version 4.18 of JUnit. Do you mean 4.13?

Comment: @StefanBirkner Eclipse 2020-12 (4.18).

Comment: oh sorry I thought u meant the eclipse version

Comment: What do you get when you replace `org.junit.Before` with `org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach`, delete the launch configuration and then run it again?

Comment: just checked I have 4.13

Comment: I get an error that says cannot resolve Before to a type on the @Before

Comment: Sure, you have to replace `@Before` (JUnit 4) with `@BeforeEach` (JUnit 5) too.

Comment: @howlger nothing changes I still get the same error

Comment: issue fixed my dumbass placed the library in the module path instead of the classpath hence why the classNotfOUNDexception

Answer (score 0):

JUnit 5 is split into several [artifacts](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#overview), mainly the API and the actual engine which runs the tests. The error you are seeing seems to indicate you do not have the engine available (or more precisely the platform on which the engine depends). Assuming you are using Maven, make sure you have the following dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: According to the screenshots, Maven is not used here.

Comment: Shoot, I didn't notice the screenshots. In that case that would be probably the configuration of the IDE, as you say in the comment.